# how to log client ip addresses on kubernetes ingress hosts?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

i have N number of ingresses(hosts) and pods in kubernetes.

For Example:
test1.exmaple.com
test2.examplecom

I want to log the client ips whenever there is a hit to hosts.

is this possible in kubernetes?

Comment: When you say log, do you mean ingress log or real server log? Ingress can log the client IP while real server can get the client IP via X-Forward-For header

Comment: @HangDu As long as you have something inserting the X-Forward-For header.

Comment: @Matt You are right. My nginx ingress has real_ip_header set to X-Forwarded-For header.